# ClientHandlerException while handling 401 Unauthorised from server

Tags: jersey, dropwizard, jersey-client

I am hitting a multipart API which is working fine in all 2XX and 4XX cases except 401s, it is not able to map to ClientResponse class and throws ClientHandlerException, this is how I am making the call:

```
 ClientResponse response = client.resource(uri)
                .accept("application/json")
                .header("X-FORWARDED-FOR", "X.X.X.X")
                .header("Authorization", authorization)
                .type(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE)
                .post(ClientResponse.class, part);

athorization: Basic authorization header
part: FormDataMultiPart object
```

here are the error logs:

```
ERROR [2017-06-02 21:46:01,362] [ ] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 91277b4e45d2df98
! com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
! at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:155)
! at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
! at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
! at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
! at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
```

... some more application logs and then..

```
! Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:666)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:666)
! at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1534)
```

Jersey-client version: 1.18.1